# How select POST values from different select options?

Tags: html, select

For example, I have 3 different select options:

```
<select name="FirstOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="SecondOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="ThirdOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
```

So, when I click a button, I want to **get all the values of all 3 select options** and **insert the values into the database**.

Right now, I'm using this button with a href tag but looks like it's very wrong:

```
 <a href="../reservation-confirmation?tour_id='.$tour->ID.'" class="reserveButton" name="reserveButton" click="return validateRequirement();">Reserve</a>
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrap the selects inside a form and put a submit button.
2. Add your ID as hidden fields.

Your HTML code should now be something like this :

```html
<form method="post" action="../reservation-confirmation">
<select name="FirstOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="SecondOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<select name="ThirdOption">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" value="" name="tour_id" >
<button type="submit" name="submit'> Submit </button>
</form>
```

3. On the server-side, process the responses by targeting

   ```php
   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
       $FirstOption$=$_POST['FirstOption']
       $SecondOption$=$_POST['SecondOption']
       $ThirdOption$=$_POST['ThirdOption']
       ...   //Add them into your database.
   ```
4. Remember to use prepared statements.

Comment: When I do this, how can I still call the click="return validateRequirement();"?

Comment: Please u can edit the opening form tag as follows :

<form method="post" action="../reservation-confirmation" onsubmit="return validateRequirement();">